# Understanding unsafe publication

Tags: java, multithreading, shared-memory

In JCIP 16.2 B.Goetz mentioned that

> If you do not ensure that publishing the shared reference
>   happens-before another thread loads that shared reference, then the
>   write of the reference to the new object can be reordered (from the
>   perspective of the thread consumign the object) with writes to its
>   fields.

So I would guess that it means that publishing even ***NotThreadSafe*** objects with synchronization is enough. Consider the following shared object

```
public ObjectHolder{
    private int a = 1;
    private Object o = new Object();
    //Not synchronizaed GET, SET
}

//Assume that the SharedObjectHolder published 
//with enough level of synchronization
public class SharedObjectHolder{
    private ObjectHolder oh;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public SharedObjectHolder(){
         lock.lock();
         try{
             oh = new ObjectHolder();
         } finally {
             lock.unlock();
         }
     }

     public ObjectHolder get(){
         lock.lock();
         try{
             return oh;
         } finally {
             lock.unlock();
         }
     }
}
```

Now we have *happens-before* between writng to `oh` and returning `oh` from the method `get()`. It guarantees that any caller thread observes up-to-date value of `oh`.

But, writing to `oh` fields (`private int a`, `private Object o`) during construction is not `happens-before` with wiritng to `oh`. JMM does not guarantee that. If I'm wrong, please provide a proof-reference to JMM. Therefore even with such publishing, a thread reading `oh` may observe a *partually-constructed* object.

So, what did he mean by saying that I provided in a quote? Can you clarify?

Comment: Why do you need a lock in the constructor (or in `get()`, actually)? Just make `oh` final, then the assignment happens-before the return of the constructor.

Comment: So you think that lock will guarantee that #get method can't be executed before constructor is finished? Funny

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I can't just do it final...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specifically asked for a disprove of your statement: “But, writing to `oh` fields (`private int a`, `private Object o`) during construction is not `happens-before` with writing to `oh`. JMM does not guarantee that”, have a look at [JLS §17.4.5. Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), right the first bullet:

> If we have two actions *x* and *y*, we write *hb(x, y)* to indicate that *x happens-before y*.
>
> - If *x* and *y* are actions of the same thread and *x* comes before *y* in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.
>
> …

This, together with the transitivity of *happens-before* relationships, is the most important guaranty of the JMM as it implies that we can have threads performing a sequence of actions without synchronization and only synchronizing *when needed*. But note that it isn’t relevant to establish a *happens-before* relationship between the writing of the fields of `ObjectHolder` and the write to `SharedObjectHolder.oh` as that all happens within a single thread.

The important consequence of the citation above is that there is a *happens-before* relationship between all three writes and the release of the `Lock` due to the program order. Since there also is a *happens-before* relationship between the release of the `Lock` and the subsequent acquisition of the `Lock` by another thread within `SharedObjectHolder.get()`, the transitivity establishes a *happens-before* relationship between all three writes and the acquisition of the `Lock`. It doesn’t matter in which order these three writes were actually performed, the only thing that matters is that all three are completed by the time the `Lock` is acquired.

---

As a side note, you wrote in a code comment “*Assume that the SharedObjectHolder published with enough level of synchronization*”. If we assume that, the entire `Lock` becomes obsolete as the “enough level of synchronization” used to properly publish the `SharedObjectHolder` instance is also enough for the publication of the embedded `ObjectHolder` and its fields, as all their initialization *happens-before* that publication of `SharedObjectHolder` due to the program order.

Answer (score 2):

If you only read or write `oh` per the methods above, then the lock aquired by `get()` will ensure you see all actions up to the release of the lock in SharedObjectHolder's constructor -- including any writes to `oh`'s fields. The happens-before edge you're relying on has nothing to do with the write to `oh`, and everything to do with writes (including to `oh`'s fields) happening before a lock is released, which happens before that lock is acquired, which happens before reads.

It *is* possible to see a partially-constructed `oh`, if you have a thread that reorders `get()` to happen before the constructor and the write to `oh` to happen before both of them. That's why the SharedObjectHolder instance needs to be published safely.

(That said, if you can publish SharedObjectHolder safely, I don't see why you couldn't just publish the original `oh` reference safely.)

Answer (score 0):

We have:

1. Write of ObjectHolder values
2. Write of oh
3. Unlock of lock
4. Lock of lock
5. Read of oh and ObjectHolder values.

There are happens-before relations between 1, 2, 3 and 4, 5 because they are in program order and in the same thread.

There is a happens-before relation between 3 and 4 because of the lock.

So there is a happens-before relation between the writes of ObjectHolder values and the reads in the other thread because of transitivity.